# Decimal to hexadecimal converter

Tags: c

I'm new into programmring, and i've got my first assignment. The assignment is about converting a decimal input to decimal AND hexadecimal.
If i fx type 15 (input), i should get 15 and F as output.
I am not to build the program from scratch. My teacher gave me a template in Atmel Studio (the template is called BasicIO, if i recall correctly).
This is what I've done so far:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "usart.h"

int main(void) {    

    uart_init(); // open the communication to the microcontroller
    io_redirect(); // redirect input and output to the uart

    int input=0;

    while(1) {
        printf("Input a number\n");
        scanf("%d %x", &input, &input);
        printf("You wrote %d\n", input);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are no errors when compiling the program, but i never get an understandable output, whenenver i type something in. Can anyone see the reason for that? What should i change?

This is of course C programming, and i use Atmel Studio to make the program in, and run it in Realterm with an Arduino.

PS: As i told, it was a template. The only things that I have added are the %d, %x, and the &inputs, where i thought they belonged.

Comment: You seem to be taking two inputs and returning one output. Don't you want to take one input (decimal number) and return two outputs (decimal + hex number)?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i want to do! But how should i rearrange the variables then, in order to get 2 outputs from 1 input?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    scanf("%d %x", &input, &input);
    printf("You wrote %d\n", input);
```

you need

```
    scanf("%d", &input); // Read one number
    printf("You wrote %d %x\n", input, input);  // Write it out in decimal and hex.
```

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you very much, Sahu! But something else that confuses me about this template, which my teacher hasn't told me about, is the meaning of #define F_CPU 16000000UL and while(1). What are their purpose?

Comment: And, why is the input set as an integer equal to zero?

Comment: The purpose of the `#define F_CPU` line is not clear from the posted code. Maybe it is used in some .h files you are including. The `while(1)` statement keeps the program running forever unless interrupted by some signal.

Comment: The line `int input=0;` initializes `input` to `0`. It's always a good programming practice to initialize your variables.

Comment: I just came to think of that i might want to convert a decimal With Comma like 9.6 to hex.  Thats not an integer value so I might need the float funktion.  How can i implement that info the program so I can convert both integer and comma numbers?

Comment: There is no standard format specifier to write a `float` or a `double` in hex.